# container network "multi home" dns resoulution

Tags: linux, docker, networking, docker-compose, host

I try to create a simple `docker-compose.yml` file.

The problem is a container that depends on another container, but needs also access to the local network the host is connected to.

When i do `docker compose up` with the following `*.yml` the "connector" container can not resolve "backend" and results in a "EAI_AGAIN" error:

```
connector  | Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN backend
connector  |     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:109:26) {
connector  |   errno: -3001,
connector  |   code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
connector  |   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
connector  |   hostname: 'backend'
connector  | }
```

*`docker-compose.yml`*

```yaml
version: "2"
services:
  nginx:
    image: "nginx:1.23.2-alpine"
    container_name: nginx
    hostname: nginx
    volumes:
      - "./project.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/project.conf"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
  database:
    image: mongo
    container_name: database
    hostname: database
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  backend:
    image: "project/backend:latest"
    container_name: backend
    hostname: backend
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - DATABASE_HOST=database
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - database
    tty: true
  frontend:
    image: "project/frontend:latest"
    container_name: frontend
    hostname: frontend
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
  connector:
    image: "project/connector:latest"
    container_name: connector
    hostname: connector
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - BACKEND_HOST=backend
    depends_on:
      - backend
    #    net: host
    network_mode: "host"
    tty: true
```

What would be the correct way to allow the connector access to the local Network where docker is running and and allow it to resolve "backend" so that it can speak with the backend container?

Backend & connector container are node.js images.

EDIT:
The connector container needs to be receive UDP multicast packets, and talk to a HTTP API in the backend container. To not deal with IP Addresses, i want to use the container names.

Which works when all container are on the same network, but not when the connector is set to "host", but which is needed to receive multicast packets.

Comment: Can you use a fully-qualified domain name to talk to your host network environment?  Something like `other-host.dev.example.com`, not just `other-host`?

Comment: @DavidMaze Can you pleas explain that? Im not sure how a FQDN would resolve this issue. To what should i set the A record? I dont want to use a "external" DNS system. I want to provide a "Quickstart" for my application, and any other than providing the images and the yaml file would be over the top.

Comment: What are you trying to connect to, that's on the host network?  Do you have that service's DNS name?

Comment: @DavidMaze Not for this use case. The connector container need to be able to received udp multicast packets. And on the same time to talk to a HTTP API in the backend container. But to not deal with IP Adresses & allow customrs to do the same on their network in want to use the container names instead of IPs.